# how do i access instance variable of one class into other class define in other file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have one file named class1.rb this is structure

```
module Person
  class Amit
    def initialize
      @a=10
    end
  end 
end
```

another file named class2.rb

```
module Person 
  class Sumit < Amit
    def aos
      puts "#{@a}"
    end
  end
end
```

i am not able to acess variable `@a` in `Sumit` how do i do that??

Comment: Post the code where you actually use this and get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look [here(adding-an-instance-variable-to-a-class-in-ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151338/adding-an-instance-variable-to-a-class-in-ruby).

Comment: but am not able to access this variale @a

Comment: I don't understand your question `s = Person::Sumit.new` and `s.aos` => `10`

Comment: `s.instance_variable_get "@a"` => `10`

Comment: `s.instance_variable_set "@a", 15` and `s.aos`=> `15`